# "Property Get method was not found" error on OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I get the error

> Additional information: Property Get method was not found when invoking OnPropertyChanged.

The idea is that I have a `ListView` with multiple items to select and `SelectionMode="Multiple"`. Everytime an item is clicked in the `ListView` I want to add it to an `ObservableCollection<Inspection>`.

For the time being I'm doing it as so:

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="Reports"
                  Margin="0,5,0,0"
                  RelativePanel.Below="ListViewHeader"
                  SelectionMode="Multiple"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding inspectionCatalogSingleton.Inspections}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInspections, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ReportViewModel()
{
    _selectedInspections = new ObservableCollection<Inspection>();
}

private ObservableCollection<Inspection> _selectedInspections; 
public Inspection SelectedInspections
{
    set
    {
        _selectedInspections.Add(value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
} 

/*....*/

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I've set a breakpoint at the set part of the property and it enters fine however when i click continue the error rises at this line:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but you are missing a getter on your SelectedInspections property.

Comment: I'll try to implement that. The issue is though that my private property is an observablecollection where the public one is of type Inspection.

Comment: @Xeun That solved the error! Thanks!
Mind setting it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OnPropertyChanged will instruct wpf to update all referenced Bindings it needs a way to GET the value of the Property.

You are missing a Getter on your Property SelectedInspections.
That is why you are getting this Exception/Error Message.